# Access-Control-Allow-Origin after jQuery AJAX HEAD request

Tags: php, jquery, request, head

Okay just a simple question, everytime I try to make HEAD request via jQuery's ajax method, I get the following err msg:

Origin http://something.loc is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I suppose it is a configurable parameter on every server. The links I try to 'investigate' are any site on the net that user inputs, so there isn't a list of 'known' servers)

Before that, I successfully did id with PHP's get_headers() method, it works great.

I was wondering, what's the difference in makin requests (jQuery vs. PHP) and why can I pickup head info with PHP and I get this error when I do it in jQuery ?!

Tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the request using PHP running on your server then the request comes from you.

If you make the request using JavaScript running in your visitor's browser, then the request comes from your visitor … with your visitor's identity … and your visitor's credentials … but the data would still be available to *your* code. If the browser let you access data from arbitrary websites, then you could access your visitor's private information on those sites.

Access-Control-Origin allows a server to state that the data available for a given URI is not private, so JavaScript running on other sites is allowed to access it.